# Flutter GoRouter and receiving Firebase Push notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, gorouter

I can't figure out how to properly integrate Firebase Messaging (Push notifications) and GoRouter. Each notification can have "link" property to enable "deep linking", for example:

```json
 "notification": {
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "title": "App Testing",
        "link": "http://myapp/tasks/1"
    }
```

Where `http://myapp/tasks/1` is deep link into the app - *Application should open detail of "task" with id 1.*.

- App has enabled deep-links (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking)
- Deep links via adb or via FCM "works" - that is, GoRouter recognize it and open desired route

However typically a notification contains some "data" - for example UserId, whos notification belongs to - our application support multiple user accounts.

```json
 "notification": {
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "title": "App Testing",
        "link": "http://myapp/tasks/1"
    },
    "data": {
        "userId": "xy123"
    }
```

- If currently logged user is not same as from notification we want first login correct one.

Theoretically it could be done within `redirect` secion of GoRouter

```dart
 GoRouter(
      observers: [_routeObserver],
      initialLocation: '/',
      routes: [
        ... routes
      ],
      refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(_loginState.stream),
      redirect: (state) {
        // here we can determine if user is logged in, redirect to sign in page, etc...
        return null;
      });
```

From FCM side we can listen for upcoming message, ie

```dart
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((msg) {
      final data = msg.data;
      final userId = data['userId'];
      print('received message opened');
    });
```

From my testing

1. Firstly `onMessageOpenedApp` is called (in case app was in background, but not terminated)
2. Then, GoRouter's redirect method is called and router is redirected to notification's link

**How can I extract notification's additional data and pass it into GoRouter and work with it within redirect method**?

In an older app, app was listening for received messages, parsed received messages, processed their data, and then, manually, redirected to the proper page. **But I would like** to use GoRouter and DeepLinks feature.

Answer (score 2):

First i just wonder why would not you send the notification to the owner ( `If currently logged user is not same as from notification we want first login correct one.` ). But if that required you can add the condition like below.

Hence go_router allows us to either navigate from the context that is below the router declaration or with redirecting. So, the `refreshListenable` is not just for loginState but i would be like `appRouterState` instead. So inside the `appRouterState` would wrap up all the state that will effect the navigation inside your app like `isLoggedIn` `comingPath` then you can add logics inside the redirect

```
class AppRouterState {
    final String? comingPath; // link that you extract from notification payload
    final String? email; // if email is null isNotLoggedIn
    ...
}
```

Then your GoRouter would be like

```
GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(appRouterStateNotifier.stream),
    redirect: (GoRouterState state) {
      String? redirection(GoRouterState state) {
        final appRouterState = ref.read(appRouterStateNotifierProvider);
        final isAuthed = appRouterState.email != null;

        if (appRouterState.comingPath != state.location && appRouterState.comingPath != null) {
            return appRouterState.comingPath;
        }

        if (state.location != '/login' && !isAuthed) return '/login';
        if (state.location == '/login' && isAuthed) return '/';

        return null;
      }
      final result = redirection(state);
      return result;
    },
)
```

Hope this helps.